# Why does std::stable_partition compile without an explicit namespace specification

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, argument-dependent-lookup

I am working on Ubuntu with

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
```

The following code is an example provided at [cplusplus.com entry about std::stable_partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_partition/)

That's not an exact copy however, I removed the namespace scope qualifier (`std::`) from the call to the `std::stable_partition` of the `<algorithm>` header.

I expect the program to not compile when I simply feed it to the g++ like that:

```
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++14 sp_test.cpp
```

however it compiles with no errors or even warnings.

Does anyone know why?

It seems as if it has been written `using std::stable_partition` somewhere under the hood of the `algorithm`.

I am new to C++ and g++ so I'd would also like to know whether it is an adequate question or not, i.e. should I ever bother with such (seeming) violations of the expected behaviour of the g++.

```
// stable_partition example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::stable_partition
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool IsOdd (int i) { return (i%2)==1; }

int main () {
        std::vector<int> myvector;

        // set some values:
        for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

        std::vector<int>::iterator bound;
        bound = stable_partition (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);

        // print out content:
        std::cout << "odd elements:";
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=bound; ++it)
                std::cout << ' ' << *it;
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "even elements:";
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=bound; it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
                std::cout << ' ' << *it;
        std::cout << '\n';

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl. This is, however, not guaranteed to work since `std::vector<int>::iterator` is not required to have `std` as an associated namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Your implementation happens to define `std::vector<int>::iterator` inside the `std` namespace, therefore name lookup for `stable_partition` implicitly searches inside `std`.

This is not portable code, because `std::vector<int>::iterator` may be a typedef of some type that is not directly declared within `std` (it may be in a nested namespace, or a namespace with a reserved name, or something like that), so argument-dependent lookup will not necessarily search inside `std`.